# How can I perform a piece of macro for each observation in sas data step?

Tags: sas

Suppose I allow user to write his own variable calculation macro using a common user interface:

```
%macro calculate(var_name, var_value);
%* Some user-defined calculation;
%mend calculate;
```

Then in a data step, I can calculate a new variable using the user-defined macro:

```
data dataset;
    set dataset;
    new_var = %calculate('variable1', variable1); * This doesn't work. It just shows my indication.
run;
```

Where variable1 is a variable in dataset. Here, I want to pass in the variable name and the actual value of the variable. After the calculation, put the value in new_var.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: would you give an example of the kind of user-defined calculation you are expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this work, but you are probably writing the macro incorrectly. You have to remember that SAS macros are essentially text preprocessors: they input the code you have written and output code to feed to SAS [1].

So here is a simple "addition" macro:

```
%macro calculate (var_name, var_value);
  &var_name + &var_value;
%mend;

data one;
  input a@@;
  b = %calculate(a, 3);
  c = %calculate(a, a);
cards;
1 3 -2 4
;
run;

proc print data=one;
run;
```

The macro facility will replace the `%calculate` bits with the code generated by the macro, and SAS will actually see the following:

```
%macro calculate (var_name, var_value);
  &var_name + &var_value;
%mend;

data one;
  input a@@;
  b = a + 3;
  c = a + a;
cards;
1 3 -2 4
;
run;

proc print data=one;
run;
```

You can see it for yourself on the log file  with the `options mprint` statement

Unfortunately, this will not cover all potential calculations. You might want to look up `PROC FCMP` for a way to generate custom functions/subroutines usable in the DATA step.

[1] I know it is more complicated than that, but you can get far thinking like this.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to how I recode a particular variable. Various datasets require a recode of Australian states. The code runs over a number of lines. As the code is fairly straight forward and needed in a number of programs, I prefer to store it in a macro and make a simple call within each program - saving seven lines of code.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and for mentioning PROC FCMP - FCMP is definitely the way to go. See cmjohns answer below for an example.

Answer (score 6):

Is it required that you achieve this with macros?  This sounds like a situation where [`PROC FCMP`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002890483.htm) would be most useful as it allows you to define your own functions or subroutines (fcmp="function compiler") that can used in a data step just like a built-in function.

Here is a simple example:

```
proc fcmp outlib=sasuser.funcs.math;
  function calc(var);
     newvar=log(var); /*user defined stuff here - can be simple or complex*/
     return(newvar);
  endsub;
run;

option cmplib=sasuser.funcs; /*tell SAS where to look for functions*/
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  newvar=calc(height); /*call your new function */
  put newvar=;
run;
```

Comment: Good point. For this question, Aniko's answer is closer to what I am looking for and is simpler. But I will definitely look into proc fcmp. Thanks for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post, but I think it's worth mentionning this.

Here's a solution that allows using a macro routine as we would a function. This is accomplished with the help of the SAS `resolve()` function. Whatever follows "%then" (in this case it's text but it could be a number) corresponds to what we would put in the return() part of a "real function".

```
%macro compare(v1, v2);
  %if &v1 > &v2 %then v1 is greater than v2;
  %else v2 is greater than v1;
%mend;

data check (drop = macroCall);
  input v1 v2;
  macroCall = cats('%compare(', v1, ',', v2, ')');
  result = resolve(macrocall);
  datalines;
1 2
2 1
;
```

Results:

```
v1  v2  result
1   2   v2 is greater than v1
2   1   v1 is greater than v2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common point of confusion. The problem is that SAS processes all macro code in your program BEFORE any of the regular code. So when it calls `%calculate('variable1', variable1);`, it doesn't yet have access to the data in the data set.

That said, it would be easier to help you come up with a solution if I had an example of what you might mean by `%*Some user-defined calculation;`.